# Xamarin.MAC WebView Remote Debug

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.mac

We have a Xamarin Mac App that contains a WebView. When we load a local html into the view the page stop loading contents (javascript error 
probably). Only happen in some pages.

Any one knows some way to debug the webview ?(display developer tools, remote debug or similar).

We have used firebug too, but with no lucky..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging a `UIWebView` within Cocoa is a little archaic (with iOS you can perform remote debugging via macOS's Safari).

Note: I am assuming you are using UIWebView as you did not specify MK or UI, or if you are using Xamarin.Forms to host your UI.

Obtain your App's Bundle indentifer:

[image]

From the cmd line enable `WebKitDeveloperExtras` for your app bundle id:

```
defaults write com.sushihangover.aFormsBaseTestHost WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true
```

Run your app (assumably via VS4M), and right click on the web view:

[image]

Choose "Inspect Element" and then toggle to the console tab for your javascript debugging.

[image]